# Find the index of last non-zero value per column of a 2-D array

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Given a 2-D array, `x`, I would like to find the indices of bottom-most non-zero element at each column.   For example, if

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [1, 5, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

the result should be `[2, 1, 0, 2]`.

One obvious way to do so is

```
 [col.nonzero()[0].max() for col in x.T]
```

I am, however, a bit concerned that the above may not be optimal in terms of performance.  Are there any more efficient ways to do so?

Answer (score 2):

In order to establish what method is more efficient, it's important to compare how several implementations perform while the input data scales. (In that case, a 2-D array.)

For the sake of consistency, in case there's no element different than zero in the column, the returned index is -1.

The presented code `[col.nonzero()[0].max() for col in x.T]` wasn't considering that special case, of a column only containing zeros, where `col.nonzero()` would return an empty array (and cause an exception while trying to use it).

#### Possible approaches

**A.1:** use only built-in Python functions, ignoring NumPy

```
[max(c) if (c:=[i for i, val in enumerate(col) if val]) else -1 for col in zip(*x)]
```

**A.2:** use built-in Python functions and NumPy transposed `numpy.ndarray.T`

```
[max(c) if (c:=[i for i, val in enumerate(col) if val]) else -1 for col in x.T]
```

**B:** use `numpy.ndarray.nonzero` function and the transposed array, but in a comprehension for each column

```
[c.max() if (c:=col.nonzero()[0]).size else -1 for col in x.T]
```

**C.1:** use no transposition nor comprehension, just the `numpy.argmax` function over the reversed columns

```
np.where(np.count_nonzero(x, axis=0)==0, -1, (x.shape[0]-1) - np.argmin(x[::-1,:]==0, axis=0))
```

**C.2:** use no transposition nor comprehension, just the `numpy.argmin` function over the reversed columns

```
np.where(np.count_nonzero(x, axis=0)==0, -1, (x.shape[0]-1) - np.argmax(x[::-1,:]!=0, axis=0)),
```

#### Performance comparison

In the following comparison, those cases are executed over an input data that increase exponentially in size.

The input data is a square 2-D NumPy array, and its elements are randomly generated integers, with 50% probability of been 0, and 50% of been any number from 1 to 9 (equially distriuted).

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot

perfplot.bench(
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(1, 14)],  # 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ..., 2k, 4k, 8k
    setup=lambda n: np.random.choice(range(10), size=(n, n), p=[0.5]+[0.5/9]*9),
    kernels=[
        lambda x: [max(c) if (c:=[i for i, val in enumerate(col) if val]) else -1 for col in zip(*x)],
        lambda x: [max(c) if (c:=[i for i, val in enumerate(col) if val]) else -1 for col in x.T],
        lambda x: [c.max() if (c:=col.nonzero()[0]).size else -1 for col in x.T],
        lambda x: np.where(np.count_nonzero(x, axis=0)==0, -1, (x.shape[0]-1) - np.argmin(x[::-1,:]==0, axis=0)),
        lambda x: np.where(np.count_nonzero(x, axis=0)==0, -1, (x.shape[0]-1) - np.argmax(x[::-1,:]!=0, axis=0)),
    ],
    labels=["A.1", "A.2", "B", "C.1", "C.2"],
).show()
```

[image]

Those results show that you should go with approach **C.1** or **C.2** if the 2-D array is big enough. The threshold seems to be around 10x10 size:

[image]

So, it will depend on your data: if the size of the 2-D array is like the one you provided as an example (a 6x6 or less), you should consider using **A.1**, **A.2** or even the initially proposed approach **B**.

(In that case, further examination should be done in that size range to verify if it's invariant to hardware, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Numpy does not provide a way to do that directly (`np.argmin` and `np.argmax` find the *first* occurrence and not the last). Thus, a trick is needed.

The thing is finding the last non-zero value per column is similar to finding the first non-zero value per column if columns are flipped.

Here is an implementation using `np.argmin` to find the first :

```py
(x.shape[0]-1) - np.argmax(x[::-1,:]!=0, axis=0)
```

You should ensure that there is at least one non-zero value per column for the result to be fine.

Comment: As you correctly said, it doesn't work if a column only contains zeros: in this case, the index of the bottom-most non-zero element of the column is wrongly informed as been the last one (the last valid index).

A solution is to identify when a column only contains zeros, and inform -1 as the index:

`np.where(np.count_nonzero(x, axis=0)==0, -1, (x.shape[0]-1) - np.argmax(x[::-1,:]!=0, axis=0))`